# Dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (with bootable pendrive) freezes during installation

Tags: windows-10, freeze, dualboot, ubuntu-20.04

My notebook config is the following:

- Acer Nitro AN515-51
- Windows 10 64bit
- Processor Intel Core i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 2808 Mhz
- BIOS mode UEFI
- RAM of 16,0 GB

I used Rufus to setup the pendrive, downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 LTS AMD64, and disabled secure boot in BIOS.

The problem is that, after Ubuntu is initialized, the installation process freezes and can't be concluded. Any ideas on how to solve would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Download the image and create the usb again looks like could be bad if after that you still getting this issue maybe it is the usb and try whit other one !

Comment: Would make any difference to tell you that the USB is brand new?

Comment: Someone told me that alternativelly downloading the iso, say through Torrent, lessens the chance of file corruption. So I did that. And I also recreated the USB with the "new" image (selecting the UEFI schem), but the installation is still infinitely loading through the above mentioned step. Should I try something like the MBR schem and changing to legacy mode in the BIOS?

Comment: can you boot the live usb i mean you can load ubuntu live whitout installing ?

Comment: Yes, I think so, and I will search how to do that. But how would that help me understand the initial problem?

Comment: the iso image from ubuntu unless server have a live distro that it is for testing purpose you should see if you are available to boot correctly from the usb, honestly it has to much time I don't use windows and as i remember the usb creators has always there modes to do things if you are available to boot ubuntu and you have other usb i will try create another usb from ubuntu directly before alter the bios but well could be easy check it like this boot the installation and then press the x in the right top corner to close it after that ubuntu it self going to take you to the desktop !